# HashSet's Entries Give ConcurrentModificationException When Iterated Over

Tags: java, multithreading, exception, generics, collections

I'm having a problem when testing a class that uses a hashset, when I iterate over the elements, I'm getting a `ConcurrentModificationException` even though, as far as I can tell (Single threaded app), only one thread ever accesses the class at any time. This breaks when two identical entries are added to the list.

```
private final HashSet<?> entries = new HashSet<>(10);
/**
 * Updates an existing entry if it exists, if not, adds it to the library.
 *
 * @param <T> The type to add
 * @param object The object to test for existence of and to update to
 * @param key The class of the object
 */
public <T> void add(T object, Class<T> key) {
    this.entries.stream().filter((entry) -> (object.equals(entry.getStorage()))).forEach(this.entries::remove);
    this.entries.add(new ClanLibraryEntry<>(object, key));
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note the javadoc for [HashSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html):

> The iterators returned by this class's iterator method are fail-fast:
>   if the set is modified at any time after the iterator is created, in
>   any way except through the iterator's own remove method, the Iterator
>   throws a ConcurrentModificationException.

This does not actually require multiple threads. It only requires the set being modified by something other than the `Iterator` itself.

Answer (score 1):

You're using streams, so this code violates the general streams principle against *non-interference*. See the [java.util.stream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html) package documentation in the section on "Non-interference". This is essentially a generalization of the fail-fast property of iterators that others have cited. The streams implementation doesn't necessarily use the source collection's iterator, so that rule doesn't apply directly; however, the concept is the same: you mustn't modify the stream's source while the stream is in operation. The penalty may be a `ConcurrentModificationException` if you're lucky (because this tells you the code is doing something wrong) or if you're not lucky, inconsistent or incorrect results.

It looks the intent is simply to remove certain matching elements. The `Collection` interface has a default method `removeIf` that, given a predicate, does exactly this. You can use this instead of streams. Here's the code:

```
this.entries.removeIf(entry -> object.equals(entry.getStorage()));
```

Answer (score 0):

The following are from the HashSet manual (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html):

The iterators returned by this class's iterator method are fail-fast: if the set is modified at any time after the iterator is created, in any way except through the iterator's own remove method, the Iterator throws a ConcurrentModificationException. Thus, in the face of concurrent modification, the iterator fails quickly and cleanly, rather than risking arbitrary, non-deterministic behavior at an undetermined time in the future.